# Couchbase - what happens if 60% of Machine RAM is not free?

Tags: couchbase

Couchbase `cluster-init` command takes 60% of RAM is memory size is not specified. What happens if 60% of RAM is not free and I run `couchbase-cli cluster-init` without memory parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The Couchbase *server RAM quota* specified the maximum amount of RAM to be used by the data service for caching documents.

In the scenario you described, the server would correctly start and operate, but over time if you added sufficient data to Couchbase then it would eventually attempt to allocate more RAM than the server had.

What happens next would depend on your OS and how it is configured. If you had swap space configured you'd likely start swapping to disk, if not (and you were running on Linux) then you may hit the kernel's *OOM-Killer* which would start terminating processes to obtain memory - and as it often kills the biggest process you'd probably find the Couchbase Server `memcached` process being killed :)